# SQL Database design guidance

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to design a database but having some slight issues.

I am trying to store project details over two separate pages.  When the user first creates a new project, they input the project name and then select the user and client.  I have an image to demonstrate this.

[image: mockup of data-entry form for specifying a project name and such.]

After this, the user is moved to the project page.  Here, they select the department and a document for that department (the department will have several documents available) and then they start filling in the required information for that selected document.  Once again, I have an image to demonstrate.

[image: mockup of a data-entry form for picking a Department and specifying brief name, due date, and such.]

So I have a users and clients table, and I link this to my projects table.  I then thought about linking a departments table to my projects table.  In the departments table, I will have a foreign key for all the different departments, and then create an individual table for these.  And for the individual table departments, I will have a foreign key to all the documents that department needs to complete.  Its not complete, but my [EER diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) looks something like this.

[image: Enhanced entity–relationship model diagram]

For some reason though, I do not feel that I am handling this correctly.  I feel that a user should be linked to a department, and maybe departments linked to clients?

Going off my images as to what I am trying to do, I was hoping someone could guide me to designing the database correctly.

Just some additional information, in the first image, Project Client will be prepopulated with clients and Project User prepopulated with users.  In the second image, Department and Documents will be prepopulated with the different departments, and the documents available for the selected department.

Answer (score 1):

So, I think tblDepartments and tblDocumentOne is your critical point. My idea:

**tblDepartments:**

- ID
- departmentName

**tblDocumentOne:**

- ID
- departmentID
- documentName

Then in tblProjects you just need the ID from tblDocumentOne. For getting the departmentName later, you have just to join the both tables above.

If the entries in the tables are changing a lot, it may be help full if you have created and modified columns, each as a datetime field. You can create these entries which triggers.

Maybe that is also a point for you: I don't like to have normal ID's shown to the user, because it is easy to get another value, try some kind of manipulation, … I use UUID's for that, which I also create by a trigger. The field should be a varchar.

**UPDATE:**

If you have a lot of Documents in your Project, then I would «split» tblProjects, that means:

**tblProject:**

- ID
- projectName
- clientID
- userID

**tblProjectDetails:**

- ID
- projectID
- documentID

Comment: Thanks for your input.  So if I have lots of different documents, I would list them all in the projects table?  Even if not all these documents will be used?